# How to find the last element inbetween some dummy elements in array list

Tags: java, xml

I need to find the previous and next valid element in an arraylist. For example my arraylist contain

`specialcharArray = ["dummy", "dummy",1.xml, "dummy","dummy","2.xml, "dummy","dummy","dummy","dummy", "3.xml"]`

Let us consider am in `3.xml` and i need to go to 2.xml. How to find the index of previous xml and suggest some idea.

My code:

`if(!specialcharArray .get(arrayindex).equals("dummy")) {
   arrayindex = arrayindex-1;
  }`

But this logic works only for one dummy but i dont know how many dummy element available. Any idea post here.

Comment: as "if" loop is used it is executed only once,you need to use iterations

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while(index >= 0 && "dummy".equals(specialcharArray.get(index))) { index--; }
```

.. after, check index != -1 to make sure it found one.